# How to do an operation alongside Component initialization when a route is activated

Tags: angular

For this particular angular route in my Angular 10 app I would like to make a local service call to set a state attribute - loginService.setAuthenticationSolution("okta") - alongside the OktaCallbackComponent. How do I do that?

Note - OktaCallbackComponent is a ready to use component that is part of [Okta Angular npm standard library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@okta/okta-angular#oktacallbackcomponent)

```js
const Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login/callback',
    component: OktaCallbackComponent
  }]
  
  @NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(Routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of 2 ways to achieve what you're asking:

1. Embed the `OktaCallbackComponent` in a custom component `CustomOktaCallbackComponent` and call the service method from inside that custom component.
2. Subscribe to routing events somewhere higher up in your project structure (perhaps at the root of the module) and trigger the service method there.

```
...
constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.events
        .pipe(filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd))
        .subscribe((e: NavigationEnd) => {
            if (e.urlAfterRedirects == '/login/callback') {
                // call service method
            }
         });
}
...
```